# How to correlate different MRI sequences images in NIFTI format?

Tags: python, registration, coordinate-systems, itk, medical-imaging

I am new on **Medical Imaging**. I am dealing with MRI images, namely T2 and DWI.

I uploaded both images with `nib.load`, yet each sequence image has a different number of slices (volume, depth?). If I select one slice (z coordinate), how can get the corresponding slice on the other sequence image? ITK does it correctly, so maybe something in the NIFTI header could help?

Thank you so much for reading! I also tried interpolation, but it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

If ITK does it correctly, why not just use ITK?

If you insist on hand-rolling your own index <-> physical space conversion routines, take a look at how ITK [computes those matrices](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/v5.2rc01/Modules/Core/Common/include/itkImageBase.hxx#L167-L191) and the publicly accessible [methods which use them](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/v5.2rc01/Modules/Core/Common/include/itkImageBase.h#L428-L590). For being specific to NIFTI, take a look at ITK's [NIFTI reader](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/v5.2rc01/Modules/IO/NIFTI/src/itkNiftiImageIO.cxx) which sets the relevant metadata in `itk::Image`.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the NIFTI, namely affine, and extracting the translation Transformation Matrix to create a mapping from the T2 to the DWI voxels.

Hint: nibabel.